# Чи має запозичений термін “інфографіка” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: терміни, синоніми

Відповідно до [визначення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0) Вікіпедії:

> **Інформаційна графіка** або **інфографіка** (англ. Information graphics; infographics) — це графічне візуальне подання інформації, даних або знань, призначених для швидкого та чіткого відображення комплексної інформації.[1](https://uk.m.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&fulltext=search&searchToken=9rvflsyc8wwam5oaawj2r8qvn) Вона може покращити сприйняття інформації, використовуючи графічні матеріали для того, щоб підвищити можливості зорової системи людини бачити моделі і тенденції.[3](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) Процес створення інфографіки можна розглядати як візуалізацію даних, створення інформаційних схем та моделей подання інформації.[2](https://uk.m.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&fulltext=search&searchToken=9rvflsyc8wwam5oaawj2r8qvn)

У [Вікісловнику](https://uk.m.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&fulltext=search&searchToken=9rvflsyc8wwam5oaawj2r8qvn), сайті "[Ділова українська мова](http://dilova.at.ua/search/?q=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0)", [Загальному народному англійсько-українському словнику](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) не вказано жодного синоніму.

Пошук по [Практичному словнику синонімів української мови](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Praktychnyi_slovnyk_synonimiv_ukrainskoi_movy_5-te_vyd_2014/) (П’яте видання, 2014 рік) Караванського Святослава, теж результатів не приніс.

Отже, чи має запозичений термін “інфографіка” синоніми українського походження?

Comment: Вельми сумнівно, шчо існує затверджена сутямка, очевидно, такого менї не довести. Натомість можна зазначити, те складенне з слів _інформаційна — [відомість](https://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1316)_, прикм. _довідковий_, та _графіка_ — _[рисунок](https://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1311)_. [Правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#prasklad) пропонує забагато варіянтів напису. Можна утворити наприклад _[відом](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/7084-vidom.html)рис_, але тодї проблема зрозумілости, бо ось анґліцізми тут прижилися доволї сильно.

Answer (score 1):

**ЧАСТКОВА ВІДПОВІДЬ**

Однозначного відповідника, на жаль, немає (принаймні безліч переглянутих мною джерел інформації такої не подають). Ймовірно через те, що це слово доволі недавно почали використовувати у лексиконі.

На [цьому](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/infohrafika) сайті існує безліч варіантів, однак це не є офіційна загальноприйнята інформація, а, радше, новотвори. До таких належать:

> ***ясновид, очезвідка, письморис, відобраз, ясновидка*** тощо.